# How would I build this query, if it's possible?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I am facing a challenge on a WordPress project I am working on, and I am hoping that someone can give me a tip on the best way to accomplish this. So I am using Advanced Custom Fields on a custom post type, and I have about 10 different fields made. I am having to build a search that needs to match the value in the advanced custom fields and return the post id.

The custom fields stores it's data in the wp_postmeta table and looks something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
|------------------------------------------|
| 1      | 24      | state    | CA         |
| 2      | 24      | city     | Yuba City  |
| 3      | 24      | type     | Full time  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

(with a lot more, but keeping it short).

So if my search fields are "State", "City", and "Job Type" and all three are filled in, what I need to happen is to return the post_id if all three meta values match what was searched for.

I've never had to do something like this where they are in multiple rows, so I'm not entirely sure how I would go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation.  One method uses `join`.  For instance:

```
select ps.post_id
from wp_postmeta ps join
     wp_postmeta pc
     on ps.post_id = pc.post_id and
        ps.meta_kay = 'state' and ps.meta_value = 'CA' and
        pc.meta_key = 'city' and pc.meta_value = 'Yuba City' join
     wp_postmeta pt
     on pt.post_id = ps.post_id and
        pt.meta_key = 'type' and pt.meta_value = 'Full time';
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could do joins within the same table, that is awesome. So I took what you showed me here and I did some research on joins within the same table and have a much better understanding. Now what I'd like to ask is, are you able to join that many in one table? Reason I ask is that I can get it to work up to state. But when I also add the join for the city, it stops returning anything.

Comment: @lpangm03 . . . Well, do you want an index on `wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)`.

Comment: Sorry, you can ignore my previous question. I figured out what I did wrong and why it wasn't returning a value after I added a third join. When I re-wrote the code to get an understanding of what is going on there, instead of joining by post_id, I typed meta_id instead and threw it all off. So I understand now.  Thank you, you were a great help and taught me something new!